# shortcut to goto method definition in rails with textmate

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

With Netbeans or Eclipse I would <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click on the function name to go to the method definition. Are there any shortcuts for this in Textmate ?

Answer (score 5):

There's a [CTags bundle](https://github.com/textmate/ctags.tmbundle) that will allow something like that. Even though it looks old, it does still work - I use it a lot myself

Answer (score 0):

**Ctrl-H** is an option to show the API documentation for the current word.
But this doesn't work for any other methods or class that may be defined or included in your project. For those I've written a TextMate Bundle command (you can easily assign it to **Ctrl+]** for example) that lookup for the definition of the class or method under the caret and displays it in a tooltip, along with the file name and the line where it was find.

Check it out: **[Add a shortcut to TextMate to lookup a class or method definition in a tooltip](http://claudiofloreani.blogspot.com/2011/10/add-shortcut-to-textmate-to-lookup.html)**
Hope you'll find it useful ;)